# Nav bar not allowing for titled button to click through to page

Tags: html, css, nav

This is the code to my nav bar. The list items all click through fine to their respective pages, but actually clicking on the nav bar titles for each page doesn't allow for clicking through to the entire page (I created a work around when testing by adding the homepages for each section in the list, but obviously don't want that).

```html
<container-fluid>
  <!-- Navigation add new page links to the href and replace #-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="navbar-corrie">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="./main.html">
      <!--connect to landing page-->
      <img src="./images/Logo.png" width="100" height="100" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="" />
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0 ">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link active dropdown-toggle" href="./main.html" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Home
                        </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="./main.html">Home</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#introduction">Introduction</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#introduction">Mission</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#audience">Audience</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link active dropdown-toggle" href="./resources.html" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Resources
                        </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="./resources.html">Resources</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#needhelp">Need Help Now?</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#mrusupports">MRU Supports & Services</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#accessibility">Accessibility</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link active dropdown-toggle" href="./campusstructure.html" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Campus Structure
                        </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="./campusstructure.html">Campus Structure</a>
            <!--This is page location ex: ./pagename.html-->
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#supportchannels">Systematic Support Channels</a>
            <!-- This is section location call id name ex: #sectionIDName-->
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#healthpolicies">Health Policies</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link active dropdown-toggle" href="./studentsupport.html" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Student Support
                        </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="./studentsupport.html">Student Support</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#earlyindicators">Early Indicators</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#crisismanagement">Crisis Management</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#selfhelp">Self-Help</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link active dropdown-toggle" href="./research.html" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Research
                        </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="./research.html">Research</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Students & Mental Health</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update with relevant CSS and plugins to make a [mcve]

Comment: Pretty sure that Bootstrap disables this deliberately, because those links are togglers for the sub-menus below them - and they toggle on click. Having two different behaviors assigned to the same user action, is not a good idea.